# insert data into mysql from json encoded data (pinterest api oauth) using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, oauth, pinterest

I have user information in json format retrieved from pinterest api (oauth)

```
$me = $pinterest->users->me(array(
'fields' => 'username,first_name,last_name,image[large]'
));
```

when I print (echo) data using json decode

```
$array_data = json_decode($me); 
echo "<pre/>";print_r($array_data);

foreach ($array_data as $key=>$value){

    if($key == 'image'){
        echo $key. " url is=" . $value->large->url .'<br/>';
    }else{

        echo $key. "=" . $value .'<br/>';
    }
}
}
```

result :

```
stdClass Object
(
[id] => 195414208739840616
[username] => rajivsharma033
[first_name] => Rajiv
[last_name] => Sharma
[bio] => 
[created_at] => 
[counts] => 
[image] => stdClass Object
    (
        [large] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/rajivsharma033_1459712414_280.jpg
                [width] => 280
                [height] => 280
            )

    )

)

id=195414208739840616
username=rajivsharma033
first_name=Rajiv
last_name=Sharma
bio=
created_at=
counts=
image url is=https://s-media-cache- 
ak0.pinimg.com/avatars/rajivsharma033_1459712414_280.jpg
```

Now I want to insert that data into MySQL. how to do it.
I have tried:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pinterest(pin_id) VALUES" .$value;
 $query_signup = mysqli_query($MySQLi_CON, $query);
```

but It is showing error :

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\a\pinterestlogin\callback.php on line 38

Help Me.

Comment: You should be treating the data from the API as user submitted data and validate and then use a prepared statement. No user-submitted or 3rd party data should be let anywhere near your database without first being **validated** and then a **prepared statement** used

Answer (score 0):

`$value` is an object when it's hitting the element with index 'image' as you iterate your decoded pintrest content array.  Your Mysql insert expects a string, not an object.

First, I'd recommend calling json_decode with true, to convert everything to associative arrays, unless you need to treat something in the body as an object.

```
$array_data = json_decode($me, true);`
```

Then check when `$value` is an object or an array and prior to your mysql insert either:

- Convert the images object to a json string and store that `$value = json_encode($value);`
- Serialize the image object `$value = serialize($value);`;